# Using MPI spawn on the clusters failed

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi, mpi4py

I recently try to perform a parallel model-fitting and cross-validation on a cluster with CentOS. Because I need to conduct a 10-fold cross-validation, I start 10 processes initially by the command:

mpirun -np 10 --bynode -hostfile ./my_hostfile python my_program &

In each of the process (which does one fold computation), a model-fitting is performed at first. Due to the model fitting can be parallelly executed, I spawn some additional processes by the MPI spawn function. The number of the additional processes can not be pre-determined, so I really need to spawn them!

Such program works perfectly on my own workstation (single node). However, when I try to run it on the cluster (cross-nodes), I got the following error messages:

[fs3:06947] [[50533,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 758

and all the processes terminates. I cannot figure out why it this. I am using the python library mpi4py, which binds to the open mpi.

Update:

The hostfile just contains the node list I preserved. There is no 'max_slots' or 'slots' specification in it. And I am sure I have preserved enough nodes for this computation.

Comment: You have to provide more information, e.g. what is the content of `./my_hostfile`. Probably there are not enough slots defined there for running new processes.

Comment: Sorry for missing such information. The hostfile just contains the node list I preserved. There is no 'max_slots' or 'slots' specification in it. And I am sure I have preserved enough nodes for this computation.